# python-returning after failiure of cv2.VideoCapture(0

Tags: python, camera, multiprocessing, video-streaming, opencv

I have the following code in python3:

```
import cv2
import sys
import os
import requests

while True:
    try:
        stream =  cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
```

But cv2.VideoCapture(0) returns an error in the commandline -in  red- and never follows the except statement.

I want to return from the program once the cam fails; how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Once the camera fails, its status is not opened:

```py
while True:
    try:
        stream =  cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not stream.isOpened():
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
```

OpenCV Python is implemented in CPyton. The `try...catch...` will not work if the native code does not support it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The execution of the code gets stuck at the "stream=cv2.VideoCapture(0)"; and keeps attempting to reconnect to the cam. That literally did nothing to solve the problem.